# Find the coordinate of A and B

Tags: systems-of-equations

Question:

OA: y= 4x

AB: 3y+8x=400

OB: y=0

Find the Coordinates of A and B

I am really not sure how to do this problem.

I've tried using system of equations to see which numbers will have in common between O, A and B. But I was honestly guessing which method could work.
Could someone help me on this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to draw the three lines on a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

A is at $OA=AB$.

That is $4 x= (400-8x)/3=400/3-8 x/3$.
$20 x/3=400/3$ or $20 x=400$ or $x=20$.
$y=(400-8x)/3=(4000-8*20)/3=80$.

So A is the point, coordinate tuple A=$(20,80)$.

B is at $OB=AB$.

That is  $0=(400-8x)/3$.
$0=400-8x$ or $x=50$.

So B is the point, coordinate tuple B=$(50,0)$.

The solution in a plot is:

[image]

Comment: How would I find the area of that triangle?

Comment: This is composed out of two rectangular triangles. One is O(20,0)A, the other is (20,0)B,A. The both follow the formular ab/2. So the left area is 800 and the right is 1200. Both. add up to the area enclosed by OBA of 2000.

Answer (score 0):

The point $A$ is the intersection of $OA$ and $AB$. To find $A$, we solve the linear equation system
$y = 4x$ and $3y + 8x = 400$. Inserting the first equation into the second one, you get $12x + 8x = 400$, which is $x = 20$. Hence $A$ has the coordinates $(20, 80)$.

Similarly, to find the point $B$, we solve the linear equation system $3y + 8x = 400$ and $y = 0$ and get $x = 50$. Hence $B$ has the coordinates $(50,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much